# Using Built-In Drivers for Print Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, drivers, printing, x86-64

I have an HP LaserJet 4 Plus that I'd like to be able to map (TCP/IP) to my users. I have to give a location for the printer so that the client computer knows where to find the driver. This would be no problem if I add the x86 printer drivers to the Print server properties section of my server and pointed the GPO to the printer installed on my (x64) server.

The problem arises when I go to HP's site to find the .inf file required to install this additional x86 driver. The site tells me to just use the in-built drivers that come with Windows. I've done that in order to install the printer to my server, but it gives me x64 drivers. I need to install the x86 drivers. When I attempt to do this using the in-built drivers (right-click printer > printer properties > sharing > Additional Drivers...) it always asks me for a location of the driver that I wish to install.

Where are the built-in Windows drivers that are used so I can point this dialog box to that

or

Where can I get the x86 .inf for this printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, I managed to pull just this kind of thing (the other direction, I was looking for x86-64 drivers) from a Vista workstation's c:\windows\system32\drivers directory.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your Windows 7 clients will have the driver built in as well, so you will not have to load an x86 driver on the server at all. (It feels weird, I know.)